# An issue with tables in ConTeXt

Tags: tables, context

I have an issue while building a table with \bTABLE \eTABLE.
After 14 rows, each with 6 columns, I get the following error:

```
luatex warning  > nodes: node 53798 has an attribute list that is free already, case 1
! error:  (nodes): trying to delete an attribute reference of a non attribute nodemtx-context     | fatal error: return code: 256
```

The table in my source file looks the following (only a couple of rows of "data" are shown):

```
\startplacetable[
   title={Metric prefixes},
   reference=u0:prefixes,
   location=middle
   ]
   {
   \bTABLE
   \setupTABLE[column][1][align=left]
   \setupTABLE[column][5][align=right]
   \setupTABLE[column][6][align=right]
   \bTABLEhead
   \bTR[topframe=on, bottomframe=off, rulethickness=0.5pt, loffset=1mm, roffset=1mm]
      \bTD ordinary \eTD \bTD scientific \eTD \bTD prefix \eTD \bTD prefix \eTD \bTD example \eTD \bTD example \eTD
   \eTR
   \bTR[topframe=off, bottomframe=on, rulethickness=0.5pt, loffset=1mm, roffset=1mm]
      \bTD number \eTD \bTD notation \eTD \bTD name \eTD \bTD symbol \eTD \bTD \eTD \bTD explained \eTD
   \eTR
   \bTR[leftframe=off, rightframe=off]
      \bTD[nc=6] \eTD
   \eTR
   \eTABLEhead
   \bTABLEbody
  \bTR
     \bTD $1 000 000 000 000 000 000$ \eTD \bTD $10^{18}$  \eTD \bTD exa  \eTD \bTD E  \eTD \bTD $2$ Eflops \eTD \bTD $2$ exaflops of performance \eTD
   \eTR
   \bTR
     \bTD $1 000 000 000 000 000$ \eTD \bTD $10^{15}$  \eTD \bTD peta  \eTD \bTD P  \eTD \bTD $2$ PB \eTD \bTD $2$ petabytes of data \eTD
   \eTR
  \bTR
     \bTD $1 000 000 000 000$ \eTD \bTD $10^{12}$  \eTD \bTD tera \eTD \bTD T  \eTD \bTD $12$ TJ \eTD \bTD $12$ terajoules of energy \eTD
   \eTR
   \bTR
     \bTD $1 000 000 000$ \eTD \bTD $10^{9}$  \eTD \bTD giga \eTD \bTD G  \eTD \bTD $3$ GW \eTD \bTD $3$ gigawatts of power \eTD
   \eTR
   \bTR
     \bTD $1 000 000$ \eTD \bTD $10^{6}$  \eTD \bTD mega \eTD \bTD M  \eTD \bTD $15$ Mg \eTD \bTD $15$ megagrams of mass \eTD
   \eTR
   \bTR
     \bTD $1 000$ \eTD \bTD $10^{3}$  \eTD \bTD kilo \eTD \bTD k  \eTD \bTD $80$ km \eTD \bTD $80$ kilometers of distance \eTD
   \eTR
   \bTR
     \bTD $100$ \eTD \bTD $10^{2}$  \eTD \bTD hecto \eTD \bTD h  \eTD \bTD $990$ hPa \eTD \bTD $990$ hectopascals of pressure \eTD
   \eTR
   \bTR
     \bTD $10$ \eTD \bTD $10^{1}$  \eTD \bTD deca \eTD \bTD da  \eTD \bTD $5$ dag \eTD \bTD $5$ dekagrams of mass \eTD
   \eTR
   \bTR
     \bTD $0.1$ \eTD \bTD $10^{-1}$  \eTD \bTD deci \eTD \bTD d  \eTD \bTD $4$ dm \eTD \bTD $4$ decimeters of length \eTD
   \eTR
   \bTR
     \bTD $0.01$ \eTD \bTD $10^{-2}$  \eTD \bTD centi \eTD \bTD c  \eTD \bTD $164$ cm \eTD \bTD $164$ centimeters of height \eTD
   \eTR
   \bTR
     \bTD $0.001$ \eTD \bTD $10^{-3}$  \eTD \bTD milli \eTD \bTD m  \eTD \bTD $250$ ml \eTD \bTD $250$ milliliters of volume \eTD
   \eTR
   \bTR
     \bTD $0.000001$ \eTD \bTD $10^{-6}$  \eTD \bTD micro \eTD \bTD $\mu$  \eTD \bTD $100$ \unit{micro second} \eTD \bTD $100$ microseconds of time \eTD
   \eTR
 %  \bTR
 %    \bTD $0.000000001$ \eTD \bTD $10^{-9}$  \eTD \bTD nano \eTD \bTD n  \eTD \bTD $650$ nm \eTD \bTD $650$ nanometers of length \eTD 
 %  \eTR
   \eTABLEbody
   \eTABLE
   }
```

I'm stuck ;-(

Thanks a lot for your help,
J

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please make your code snippet be compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doig ...

Comment: The attached example (modified to be complete) compiles for me. Can you, as @Mensch suggests, show a complete compilable (but minimal) example that is failing?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll post the minimal code that fails to compile. It must be in the new post though.

Comment: You do not need to ask in a new question. Just hit the "Edit" button in this question and update your question with the complete example.

Comment: Thanks. Edited.

Answer (score 2):

I do not see your error. But the code you have seems to be wrong. You do

```
\startplacetable[...]{
  ...
}
```

With the code below I get no error.

```
\starttext
\startplacetable[
   title={Metric prefixes},
   reference=u0:prefixes,
   location=middle
   ]
\bTABLE
\setupTABLE[column][1][align=left]
\setupTABLE[column][5][align=right]
\setupTABLE[column][6][align=right]
\bTABLEhead
\bTR[topframe=on, bottomframe=off, rulethickness=0.5pt, loffset=1mm, roffset=1mm]
    \bTD ordinary \eTD \bTD scientific \eTD \bTD prefix \eTD \bTD prefix \eTD \bTD example \eTD \bTD example \eTD
\eTR
\bTR[topframe=off, bottomframe=on, rulethickness=0.5pt, loffset=1mm, roffset=1mm]
    \bTD number \eTD \bTD notation \eTD \bTD name \eTD \bTD symbol \eTD \bTD \eTD \bTD explained \eTD
\eTR
\bTR[leftframe=off, rightframe=off]
    \bTD[nc=6] \eTD
\eTR
\eTABLEhead
\bTABLEbody
\bTR
    \bTD $1 000 000 000 000 000 000$ \eTD \bTD $10^{18}$  \eTD \bTD exa  \eTD \bTD E  \eTD \bTD $2$ Eflops \eTD \bTD $2$ exaflops of performance \eTD
\eTR
\bTR
    \bTD $1 000 000 000 000 000$ \eTD \bTD $10^{15}$  \eTD \bTD peta  \eTD \bTD P  \eTD \bTD $2$ PB \eTD \bTD $2$ petabytes of data \eTD
\eTR
\bTR
    \bTD $1 000 000 000 000$ \eTD \bTD $10^{12}$  \eTD \bTD tera \eTD \bTD T  \eTD \bTD $12$ TJ \eTD \bTD $12$ terajoules of energy \eTD
\eTR
\bTR
    \bTD $1 000 000 000$ \eTD \bTD $10^{9}$  \eTD \bTD giga \eTD \bTD G  \eTD \bTD $3$ GW \eTD \bTD $3$ gigawatts of power \eTD
\eTR
\bTR
    \bTD $1 000 000$ \eTD \bTD $10^{6}$  \eTD \bTD mega \eTD \bTD M  \eTD \bTD $15$ Mg \eTD \bTD $15$ megagrams of mass \eTD
\eTR
\bTR
    \bTD $1 000$ \eTD \bTD $10^{3}$  \eTD \bTD kilo \eTD \bTD k  \eTD \bTD $80$ km \eTD \bTD $80$ kilometers of distance \eTD
\eTR
\bTR
    \bTD $100$ \eTD \bTD $10^{2}$  \eTD \bTD hecto \eTD \bTD h  \eTD \bTD $990$ hPa \eTD \bTD $990$ hectopascals of pressure \eTD
\eTR
\bTR
    \bTD $10$ \eTD \bTD $10^{1}$  \eTD \bTD deca \eTD \bTD da  \eTD \bTD $5$ dag \eTD \bTD $5$ dekagrams of mass \eTD
\eTR
\bTR
    \bTD $0.1$ \eTD \bTD $10^{-1}$  \eTD \bTD deci \eTD \bTD d  \eTD \bTD $4$ dm \eTD \bTD $4$ decimeters of length \eTD
\eTR
\bTR
    \bTD $0.01$ \eTD \bTD $10^{-2}$  \eTD \bTD centi \eTD \bTD c  \eTD \bTD $164$ cm \eTD \bTD $164$ centimeters of height \eTD
\eTR
\bTR
    \bTD $0.001$ \eTD \bTD $10^{-3}$  \eTD \bTD milli \eTD \bTD m  \eTD \bTD $250$ ml \eTD \bTD $250$ milliliters of volume \eTD
\eTR
\bTR
    \bTD $0.000001$ \eTD \bTD $10^{-6}$  \eTD \bTD micro \eTD \bTD $\mu$  \eTD \bTD $100$ \unit{micro second} \eTD \bTD $100$ microseconds of time \eTD
\eTR
 \bTR
   \bTD $0.000000001$ \eTD \bTD $10^{-9}$  \eTD \bTD nano \eTD \bTD n  \eTD \bTD $650$ nm \eTD \bTD $650$ nanometers of length \eTD 
 \eTR
\eTABLEbody
\eTABLE
\stopplacetable
\stoptext
```

[image: The table]

Comment: Thanks a lot for checking! I copied your code into my file and it does not work. The same error. It must correlate with some other content of this file but I don't not what's wrong...

Comment: What version of ConTeXt are you running? I use the latest.

Comment: mtx-context     | current version: 2019.03.21 21:39